# Pylons, SQlite and autoincrementing fields

Tags: sqlite, sqlalchemy, pylons, auto-increment

Hey!
Just started working with Pylons in conjunction with SQLAlchemy, and my model looks something like this:

```
from sqlalchemy import Column
from sqlalchemy.types import Integer, String

from helloworld.model.meta import Base

class Person(Base):
    __tablename__ = "person"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(100))
    email = Column(String(100))

    def __init__(self, name='', email=''):
        self.name = name
        self.email = email

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<Person('%s')" % self.name
```

To avoid sqlite reusing id's that might have been deleted, I want to add AUTOINCREMENT to the column "id". I've looked through the documentation for sqlalchemy and saw that the sqlite_autoincrement can be issued. 
An example where this attribute is given can be found [here](https://groups.google.com/group/sqlalchemy/browse_thread/thread/2162c4262aeca306/a6fa091f7189069d?lnk=raot&hl=en).

sqlite_autoincrement seems though to be issued when creating the table itself, and I just wondered how it can be supplied when using a declarative style of the model such as mine.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try including a `__table_args__` attribute with the arguments you would pass to `Table` constructors in the traditional (non-declarative) data definition style, e.g.:

```
class Person(Base):
    __tablename__ = "person"
    __table_args__ = {'sqlite_autoincrement': True}
```

If you have to include several arguments, use this form instead (dict has to be last):

```
__table_args__ = (
    Unique('foo'),
    # ...
    {'sqlite_autoincrement': True}
)
```

From the [Table configuration](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/declarative/table_config.html) section of the Declarative SQLAlchemy documentation:

> Table arguments other than the name, metadata, and mapped `Column` arguments are specified using the `__table_args__` class attribute. This attribute accommodates both positional as well as keyword arguments that are normally sent to the `Table` constructor.