# SQLite: How to insert with a new rowid after having deleted one?

Tags: sqlite

Suppose my table is,

```
CREATE TABLE bookmark (
    Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    Name STRING(64) 
);
```

I have inserted three rows in this table, like this:

```
Id   | Name
1    | Bookmark 1
2    | Bookmark 2
3    | Bookmark 3
```

Now If I delete the row 3, so I get this:

```
Id | Name
1  | Bookmark 1
2  | Bookmark 2
```

And now I insert a new row with name `Bookmark 4`, I get this:

```
Id | Name
1  | Bookmark 1
2  | Bookmark 2
3  | Bookmark 4
```

Should not I be expecting the following?

```
Id | Name
1  | Bookmark 1
2  | Bookmark 2
4  | Bookmark 4
```

Anyone knows how to do this?

---

Notice: It is not a SQLite behavior but more of a SQLAlchemy problem. As @CL. points out [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7WwzqTwcuLQwAkBYDmuKY7/0), it REALLY DOES what I wanted.

Comment: [Works for me](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7WwzqTwcuLQwAkBYDmuKY7/0).

Comment: @CL. It turns out to be a SQLAlchemy problem, not the fault of SQLite. Sorry for that!

Answer (score 1):

Sorry folks, finally I've found out it is caused by SQLAlchemy 1.1.13, it is not setting `AUTOINCREMENT` field for SQLite even we have specified like following,

```
db = SQLAlchemy()
id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
```

As I use Flask, when specify,

```
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_ECHO'] = True
```

The log shows that `AUTOINCREMENT` is actually not set.

After some digging, to do it for SQLite, in SQLAlchemy 1.1.13 ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4567698/220316)),

```
class Bookmark(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "bookmark"
    __table_args__ = {'sqlite_autoincrement': True}
```

For SQLAlchemy 1.2, the following may work (not tested),

```
id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, sqlite_autoincrement=True)
```

Comment: SQLite has [two different kinds of autoincrementing](http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html).

Comment: So why is SQLAlchemy not setting autoincrement for SQLite?

Comment: It does; it uses the other kind.

Comment: Yep, I mean not forcing `AUTOINCREMENT` field explictly in the SQL query, but it does auto-increments since by default a primary key integer column is taken as auto-incremented in SQLite, just reusing the ids that are not in the current table, ignoring deleted ones. Am I right?